# Associating a Package License Management App

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, lma

We have an app on the Salesforce App Exchange right now and I am looking into using the License Management App (LMA) with. I am cautious to just go ahead and link our managed package with the LMA because we have existing customers that are using our package and I don't want to accidentally interrupt their use of it. So I have these questions about the LMA:

1) Does the LMA automatically prevent users in an org that don't have License Seats from accessing records in the custom objects that are part of our managed package? I am assuming they can't access the app to edit them but can they access them from the record lists in Salesforce?

***Edit:*** I did found an answer to my first question above with this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/124306/28894 but I've not found answers to the questions below yet...

2) Before I actually associate the LMA with our package that is live on the AppExchange, I want to experiment with how it works in a separate org with a package that is not listed on the AppExchange as to not affect that live package. Is it possible to associate the LMA to a managed package that is not in the AppExchange?

<s>3) I see that the Trial lasts for 90 days. Can the duration of the trial be changed?</s> (Moved this to a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143200/changing-the-duration-of-the-license-management-app-trial) to make this question more focused.)

4) Once I associate a managed package with the LMA, can I un-associate it?

Comment: your 2nd question is not clear, please sharpen it for us to understand

Comment: @ItaiShmida I re-worded question 2. I hope its more clear now. (Sorry for the multiple edits!)

Answer (score 1):

2.LMA is for managing licenses for managed packages. I don't think that these packages have to be on the appexchange. Anyway - on the appExchange you can choose which package versions to publish and which not to publish.

4.Yes you can  un-associate it, but think about all the licenses that you have managed with this org - what would happen with?

You better review this:
[LMA Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_package_details.htm)

in the: [License Management and Support Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_intro.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I've already read the entire License Management and Support Guide. So do you know what would happen with all the licenses that we have managed with the org if we un-associate it? Would those users still have access to the app? We already have ways within the app to limit access to certain features and disable the app if needed. We are specifically looking at the LMA for its ability to limit the number of seats if we move to a new payment modal. The question is: can we undo the LMA and revert back to how it was before associating it w/o any repercussions if we don't like how it works?

Comment: I don't know what will with these licenses