# Changing the Duration of the License Management App Trial

Tags: managed-package, lma, trial

Is it possible to change the duration of the Trial status for the License Management App? I see that it is normally 90 days. Can I change it to 30 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that - open a case and request this from Salesforce support.